# Can a REST web service return more than once?

Tags: web-services

I am familiar with SOAP web services, and have done some PUT/GET/POST verbs in REST web services.  Somewhere I read that your REST web service can return a code if something goes wrong at the web service, but can it return twice?

By that I mean:  supposed your REST web service is querying a database and it is doing a lazy load, so it is taking a while.  You intend to return an array of values from the database back to the client that called the REST web service.  But while the REST web service is working on your database query, can it return a string that says "Query is 10% complete, please wait" or something like that?  Can the REST web service call another web service that somehow communicates back to the client this information?

I doubt this is possible, otherwise I would have seen it, but I ask anyway.

Target platform is Visual Studio 2010 Professional with C# and MS Sql Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

You could look at COMET, which according to wikipedia:

*...is a programming technique that enables web servers to send data to the client without having any need for the client to request it. It allows creation of event-driven web applications which are hosted in the browser.*

There are a number of articles on the web about doing this plus a couple of frameworks on sourceforge and github. However this is not trivial. I know it is possible with REST because a previous employer of mine has several real-time feeds based on RESTfull endpoints using COMET for push.

See here:

- http://www.aaronlerch.com/blog/2007/07/08/creating-comet-applications-with-aspnet/
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/emergetk/
- https://github.com/Oyatel/CometD.NET